# Drupal 7: HTTPS submit button takes to HTTP page and then redirects to HTTPS

Tags: http, https, drupal-7

i have drupal 7 based website, you can check the page here:

https://www.ticketgum.com/europa-uefa-league/champions-league--final-tickets-29-May-2019

All pages at ticketgum are HTTPS page, and if you try to go to HTTP page you will get redirected to HTTPS.

Now there is "Buy" tickets form, if you click "Buy" you should be redirected to HTTPS checkout page, but drupal 7 redirects it to checkout HTTP page, and then automatically to checkout HTTPS page, so there is DOUBLE redirect, as you can see at attached image, how can i prevent it? and fix the first redirect to HTTPS...

screen shot: https://www.ticketgum.com/http.JPG

The code in submit form function is a simple drupal_goto('checkout');

Answer (score 1):

You have to verify some configuration :

Into `settings.php` :

```
$conf['HTTPS'] = true;
$conf['base_url'] = "https://www.ticketgum.com"
```

Also you can use [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) like this :

```
drupal_goto($path, array("external" => TRUE, "https" => TRUE));
```

Otherwise you can use `redirect` form state to specify redirect after submit instead use `drupal_goto`

```
function YOURFORM_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'your_url';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, first of all if you use:

drupal_goto function this way it works:
drupal_goto($path, array("external" => TRUE, "https" => TRUE));

But in my case the problem was with redirecting in form submit,
Drupal created HTTP url instead of HTTPS in url() function because my global variable called "insecure_url" was HTTP.

You can cancel it in your drupal admin panel, just go: 
www.domain.com//admin/config/system/securepages

and uncheck "Switch back to http pages when there are no matches" option.